# How to fix 'No module named 'whitenoise'?

Tags: python, django

Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:
No module named 'whitenoise'
Exception Location:
 in _find_and_load_unlocked, line 965

I from the local computer, put the project on a hosting, and such error got out

''''''

CSS static doesn't work

Comment: It sounds like you don't have `whitenoise` installed in the hosted environment. Can't say much more than that without more details.

Comment: http://youdontdie.beget.tech/admin 
look please debug

Comment: `whitenoise` is not part of the standard python library.  Did you install it on the host?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you provided contains a possible solution:

> Your WhiteNoise configuration is incompatible with WhiteNoise v4.0
>   This can be fixed by following the upgrade instructions at:
>   http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0

Have you tried that yet?